# Should I wrap object in Mono before returning in Webflux controller?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I couldn't find an answer to it. Assume I have a simple method in my Webflux @RestController; in my case it's an Exception handler. All it does is return an effectively final object (as a Map<String, Object>). Couldn't be simpler.

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Map<String, Object> nullInfoSent(NullPointerException e) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    map.put("error", "Error occurred.");
    return map;
}
```

But is this this incorrect? Should I be wrapping the returned value in a Mono?

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> nullInfoSent(NullPointerException e) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    map.put("error", "Error occurred.");
    return Mono.just(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet is a regular Spring MVC controller; `Map` is returned immediately to the client.

You should wrap the returned value in a `Mono`(or Flux) in order to make it reactive. The framework (Spring Webflux) will subscribe to the returned `Mono` executing your pipeline(`Mono.just` in this case).

Comment: thanks, I'm still a bit confused though as to the consequences of not wrapping the Map in a Mono/Flux, as there's nothing here that would block (and the controller still appears to work normally from the client side).

Comment: @TheCornInspector There is nothing blocking, so you won't notice the difference.